# Confusion between molar gas constant and boltzmann constant?

Tags: ideal-gas, molecules, gas

So after reading reading through internet I came to the conclusion that :

For gas of any element 
PV/T = Constant of proportionality

and that constant of proportionality can be expressed in Microscopic or macroscopic properties of gas.

In Macroscopic = In terms of Mol
PV/T = nR

In Microscopic = in terms of no of particles 
PV/T = NK

Here in both cases   R and K are fixed constants 
and nR and NK are the Constants of proportionality 
Am I correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. The Boltzmann constant is equal to $\frac{R}{N_A}$, where $N_A$ is Avogadro's constant, since $1$ mole contains $N_A$ particles.